# Hiding a focused control by setting focus to a control in a subform

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to hide a subform (`frmValueChain10`) by clicking a button which is located on it and opening another (a frame located within another subform, `frmValueChain02` in the same parent form). When I try to do so, I am getting the message "You cannot hide a control that has an active status." Is it possible to do this?

Current code:

```
Form_frmValueChain02.Frame251.SetFocus
```

Comment: Excuse me, the error message is that i cannot hide a control that has the status as active.  Basically, i am on a tab control. Upon clicking a button that i have embedded in it, i would like to hide that tab and open another

Comment: What i did was set the focus on a control on another subform (in this case frmValueChain) but it still gives the error       Form_frmValueChain02.Frame251.SetFocus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting focus to controls in subforms only changes the focus within that subform. Instead, you need to SetFocus a different control on whichever form contains the control you're trying to hide. Assuming `Form_frmValueChain02` is the subform control:

```
Form_frmValueChain02.SetFocus
Form_frmValueChain02.Frame251.SetFocus
frmValueChain10.Visible = False
```

Comment: But i need the entire form frmValueChain10 to disappear altogether.  Is it possible given that the button (control) that that triggers the event is located on the same form?